# layout_gravity="center_vertical" not working

Tags: android

### My problem

I can't seem to figure out why `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` is not working in my case.

*Please note that I am not interested in solving the problem of making it vertically aligned, so much so that I am trying to understanding exactly what is the cause of this behavior itself for pedagogical reasons.*

### My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_100">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:background="@color/red_100"

        android:text="HELLO WORLD"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="2"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation will ignore the *vertical component* of any child's `android:layout_gravity` attribute. Similarly, a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation will ignore the *horizontal component* of a child's `android:layout_gravity`.

For the special case of the `center` gravity value, it's helpful to know that this behaves identically to `center_horizontal|center_vertical`, down to the actual integer value of the constants (0x11 vs 0x01|0x10). As such, using `android:layout_gravity="center"` in a vertical linear layout will be equivalent to just `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`.

As for **why**, consider this:

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>

    <View layout_gravity=top/>
    <View layout_gravity=bottom/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What would you do here? If you position the first view at the top of the screen and the second view at the bottom of the screen, then you're not really a **linear** layout.

Even though you said you're not interested in how to solve the problem, you can do so with the `android:gravity` attribute on the `LinearLayout` itself. This will cause the `LinearLayout` to stack all the views together at the top, center, or bottom of the linearlayout.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up my confusion. What about `center` though?

Comment: @AlanSTACK could you clarify the question? What do you want to know about `center`?

Comment: A `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation will ignore the *vertical component* of gravity (e.i `layout_gravity=center_vertical`) What about `layout_gravity=center`? Does it just become effectively `layout_gravity=center_horizontal`?

Comment: @AlanSTACK yes. Under the hood, `center` (0x11) is identical to `center_horizontal|center_vertical` (0x01 | 0x10) so, in this case, it would be equivalent to just using `center_horizontal`.

Comment: Could you modify your response to include this fact. I believe it will serve those in the future well. (How `center` becomes `center_horizontal` w/ `orientation=vertical` and `center_vertical` w/ `orientation=horizontal`)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Sorry to bother you but you really seem to know what your doing and I have another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849059/will-container-param-of-pageradapter-destroyitem-be-null-if-its-attached-vi If you could take a look at it... that would be woooooooonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it is but if you change your layout height to wrap content instead of match parent, it will be centered.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. There are 2 views which can result in the issue. Please be specific. Inserting the actual code snippet helps